# jQuery vTicker with vertical scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am using jQuery vTicker, But I want the whole list which user can view using the scrollbar. I don't want dynamic scroll bar. Just a simple scroll bar.
This is what I am doing.

HTML:

```
<div id="liveData" style="max-height: 490px; overflow: auto;">
    <div class="live-feeds">
        <ul>
            <li>
            /*Live data here*/
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.live-feeds').vTicker({
        speed: 800,
        pause: 2000,
        animation: 'fade',
        height: 490,
        mousePause: true,
        showItems: 50
    });
```

Does anyone have any idea how do I do this.

Comment: set your overflow to scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
direction:'down'
```

to your (.live-feeds).vTicker JS

your js should really be

```
   $(function() {$('#live-feeds').vTicker({
         speed: 800,
         pause: 2000,
         showItems: 50,
         animation:'fade',
         mousePause:true,
         height: 490,
         direction:'down'
        });
   });
```

Comment: see this link for clarification on how to style it http://mistonline.in/wp/jquery-news-ticker-with-unlimited-scrolling/

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I set the overflow to scroll and job done. I must accept your answer...